# Pandas.read_html() How to avoid putting rows with <th> elements into the header?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a HTML table.

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th> header 1 </th>
      <th> header 2 </th>
      <th> header 3 </th>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tr>
    <td> 001 </td>
    <td> A </td>
    <td> 1 </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td> 002 </td>
    <td> B </td>
    <td> 2 </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td> 003 </td>
    <td> C </td>
    <td> 3 </td>
  </tr>

</table>
```

If I want to transform this html to a table by pandas.

```py
import pandas as pd

table = pd.read_html(html, header=None)
```

I Got This

```py
    header 1    header 2    header 3
0      1          A           1
1      2          B           2
2      3          C           3
```

But I wish to put the header into the table.

```py
     0             1           2
0  header 1    header 2   header 2
1    1           A           1
2    2           B           2
3    3           C           3
```

How can I make it?  I have read the documentation for [pd.read_html](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_html.html) and can not find the solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use `numpy` `vstack`

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.vstack([df.columns, df]))
```

Comment: print("Thank you")